# How to count the realtive frequency of each letter [a-z] from a text file in Java

Tags: java

I have managed to convert any text file and removed it of all characters and numbers except for [a-z] and spaces.  I now would like to determine the relative frequency of each letter in the text file.  Please could someone give me some pointers.

Comment: Do you have a formula for the relative frequency?

Comment: the letter frequency count relative to the total number of letters in the text file.

Comment: You could store the frequencies in a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` or in `new int[65536]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hashmap to calculate the count of each characters and from that you can calculate the relative frequency

```
        public class RelativeFrequency
    {

        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            Map<Character, Integer> characterCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

            String text = "asda";// Replace it with your text

            for (int index = 0; index < text.length(); index++)
            {
                char c = text.charAt(index);
                if (null == characterCountMap.get(c))
                {
                    characterCountMap.put(c, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    characterCountMap.put(c,
                            characterCountMap.get(c).intValue() + 1);

                }
            }

            Set<Entry<Character, Integer>> entrySet = characterCountMap.entrySet();

            for (Iterator iterator = entrySet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
            {
                Entry<Character, Integer> entry = (Entry<Character, Integer>) iterator
                        .next();
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " relative frequency ="
                        + ((float) entry.getValue()) / text.length());

            }
        }
    }
```